# Iteratively assign/create multiple directories with as few lines as possible

Tags: python, loops, operating-system

I have a script that uses some directories from its home directory. The first step is to assign variable names to those directories using `os.path.join()`. However, if the directory does not exist, I need to create it. I don't know beforehand which directories do and do not exist. The solution I came up with is this:

```
import os
import sys

homepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

def make_dir(var_name,dir_name):
    var_name = os.path.join(homepath,dir_name)
    if os.path.exists(var_name) == False:
        os.mkdir(var_name)
    return var_name

pathnames = ['bands','clipfiles','ndvi','ndmi','masked','clipped','upsampled','stats_csv']      

path_to_bands = make_dir(path_to_bands, pathnames[0])
path_to_clipfiles = make_dir(path_to_clipfiles, pathnames[1])
path_to_ndvi = make_dir(path_to_ndvi, pathnames[2])
```

The `path_to_bands`, `path_to_clipfiles`, etc are the folders I will use later in the script. However, I now need a line of code for every directory I assign to a variable. Is there any way to make `path_to_bands`, `path_to_clipfiles` etc. into a list and loop over it in a few lines? In reality I have a lot of directories and I don't want it to fill up my script unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html?highlight=makedirs#os.makedirs) is pretty much perfectly suited to your use case. By passing the argument `exist_ok=True` you won't have to check if the directories are pre-existing. It also creates directories recursively so you only need to specify your bottom level directories.

Comment: Alright, that works. However, I still don't see how I can assign the directories to a variable iteratively. 

E.g. if I want to navigate to the directory 'bands' in the rest of the script, is there any way I can assign it to the variable path_to_bands without having to type it out for every single directory?

Answer (score 0):

You should `map` a slightly modified version of your `make_dir` on `pathnames`

```py
import os

homepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

def make_dir(dir_name):
    var_name = os.path.join(homepath,dir_name)
    if not os.path.exists(var_name): os.mkdir(var_name)
    return var_name

pathnames =[
    'bands',
    'clipfiles',
    'ndvi',
    'ndmi',
    'masked',
    'clipped',
    'upsampled',
    'stats_csv']      

varnames = list(map(makedir, pathnames))
```